# Issue with dispatcing an action within components

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am trying to `dispatch` an action within one of my components. I have set my action creator and `reducer`. My action creator is named `allSearches`. I am even dispatching the action within the component. However, I am getting the following result when I do a `console.log` of the `allSearches` - (coming from `mapStateToProps`).
Please see below.

return dispatch(actionCreator.apply(this, arguments)); - (seen on the console)

```
import React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import {fetchTopSearches} from '../actions/fetchTopSearches.js'
import {allSearches} from '../actions/allSearches.js'
import { Link, Route, HashRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import Search from './Searches'

class TopSearches extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount(){
    this.props.fetchTopSearches();
    this.props.allSearches();
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div className="topsearches">
       <table border="2" align="center">
         <thead>
           <th> Search Term </th>
           <th>Count </th>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
           {this.props.topSearches.map(top_search =>
             Object.keys(top_search).map(key => {
               return (
                 <tr>
                   <td>{key}</td>
                   <td>{top_search[key]}</td>
                 </tr>
               );
             })
           )}
         </tbody>
       </table>
       <HashRouter>
           <p><Link to='/searches'> All Searches </Link></p>
             <Route exact path='/searches' render={()=><Search all_searches={this.props.allSearches}/>}/>
       </HashRouter>
     </div>
     )
   }
 }

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return (
    {topSearches: state.topSearchReducer.topSearches,
     allSearches: state.allSearchesReducer.allSearches
    }
  )
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps, {fetchTopSearches, allSearches})(TopSearches);
```

Comment: Can you also provide in the question the code for your reducer and your actions?

Comment: Thank you for responding. Yes sure

Comment: export function allSearches() {
 return (dispatch) => {
   console.log("Inside Allsearches action");
   fetch('http://localhost:3001/api/v1/searches')
   .then(resp => resp.json())
   .then(allSearches => {
      console.log("Inside Action then",allSearches);
      dispatch({
         type: 'ALL_SEARCHES',
         payload: allSearches
      })
    })
 }
}

Comment: export default function allSearchesReducer(state = {allSearches: []}, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ALL_SEARCHES':
      console.log("Allsearch reducer",action.payload);
      return {allSearches: action.payload}
    default:
      return state
  }
};

Comment: Are you using redux-thunk?

Comment: Yes, I am using redux-thunk

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem lies in the fact that you are calling both your dispatch function and your props `allSearches`.

Instead of

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return (
    {
     topSearches: state.topSearchReducer.topSearches,
     allSearches: state.allSearchesReducer.allSearches
    }
  )
}
```

Try calling `allSearches` here something else, such as `searches`, for example:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
     topSearches: state.topSearchReducer.topSearches,
     searches: state.allSearchesReducer.allSearches
  };
};
```

I tried reproducing your problem here with some dummy data from a testing API:

[image: Edit sweet-wescoff-uucmb]

In the code, if you change `searches` in the `TopSearches` component back to `allSearches`, you'll see nothing will happen because now there's a dispatch function and a props called `allSearches`.

A way to avoid confusion is to create a `mapDispatchToProps`, such as:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return (
    {
     allSearches: () => dispatch(allSearches())
    }
  )
}
```

Then passing in the high order component `connect` like:

```
export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(TopSearches);
```

By doing that, you know right away the `props` that are available in your component and if you have props with the same name.

Comment: I’m glad to hear that! Don’t forget to accept the answer if there’s nothing else I can do for you.

Comment: Accepted answer.

Comment: You need to click in the answer's `check` icon, but that's okay. I'm just glad I was of any help!

Comment: Done! Thanks again!